# What slider plugin is this site using?

Tags: wordpress, slider, popover

Check this page please http://www.viralnova.com/then-and-now-celebrites/

If you scroll, you´ll see a box slides from the right with a facebook like box. I'm going crazy to figure what plugin is this.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the "How to Ask" section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The plugin's been written by themselves but if you looking for a similar then this is : http://wordpress.org/plugins/dreamgrow-scroll-triggered-box/screenshots/